# Android package installer failed silently

Tags: android, apk, packageinstaller

I tried to install the APK programmatically using PackageInstaller but it is failing without any error.
The session.commit() executing without any error and calls the callback Intent. But callback intent doesn't receive any extras.

```
 @Throws(IOException::class)
fun installPackage(context: Context, `in`: InputStream, packageName: String): Boolean {
    Log.i("install","installer called")
    Log.i("install","in iteration")
    val packageInstaller: PackageInstaller = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInstaller()
    val params = SessionParams(
        SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL
    )
    params.setAppPackageName(packageName)
    // set params
    val sessionId = packageInstaller.createSession(params)
    val session = packageInstaller.openSession(sessionId)

    Log.i("id",""+sessionId)

    addApkToInstallSession("india.apk",session);
 
    val intent =  Intent(context, InstallResultReceiver::class.java)
    intent.setAction("PACKAGE_INSTALLED")
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        context,
        sessionId,
        intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    )
    Log.i("t",""+packageInstaller.getSessionInfo(sessionId).toString())
    try {
        session.commit(pendingIntent.intentSender)
    }catch(e:Exception){
        Log.i("",""+e.stackTrace)
    }

    Log.i("Down","install committed")
    return true
}

   @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun addApkToInstallSession(assetName: String, session: PackageInstaller.Session) {
        session.openWrite("package", 0, -1).use { packageInSession ->
            assets.open(assetName).use { `is` ->
                val buffer = ByteArray(16384)
                var n: Int
                while (`is`.read(buffer).also { n = it } >= 0) {
                    packageInSession.write(buffer, 0, n)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi can i see yout InstallResultReceiver code?

Comment: Is it happen in especial scenario or all the time it happen? what is your device that  you testing on it

Comment: Hi Kavin... i am trying to solve the same issue..can you confirm that it was solved by one of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the flags on PendingIntent.getBroadcast(). Try the following:

```
var flags = 0
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
    flags = PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
}
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
    context,
    sessionId,
    intent,
    flags
)
```

Comment: `FLAG_MUTABLE` not an option:  Must be one or more of: PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE, Intent.FILL_IN_ACTION, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA, Intent.FILL_IN_CATEGORIES, Intent.FILL_IN_COMPONENT, Intent.FILL_IN_PACKAGE, Intent.FILL_IN_SOURCE_BOUNDS, Intent.FILL_IN_SELECTOR, Intent.FILL_IN_CLIP_DATA  `Is one of these equivalent?`

Comment: @RoyHinkley wich compile sdk and build tools version are you using? I think you should be using 31 to see this flags

Comment: yes, flag_mutable was added in api level 31: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent#FLAG_MUTABLE

Comment: There you have it.  I am using compile 30.  Thank you!